# Union Three or more tables with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a help to solve some problem.

I have some table `levelAsignment` with columns `level_id`, `store_id` and `user_id`. For each `user_id` I can write a query to get his `level_id`s and `store_id`s.

Also I have a table `stores`.
I need to get for each store his level and count the users of the current level and store.

It's easy, but the problem is in storing data, Because in the `levelAsignment` table the user can set all stores for some operator level.

It looks like this:

```
    level_id  |  store_Id |  user_id
       4            1           5
       1            5           5
       6            1
```

when `store_id = 1` in the `stores` table it means all stores, so I need to show all stores except 1.

```
select * from stores where id != 1;
```

so I need an advice how to organize that.

I find different ways to solve the problem, but there were many unions and conditions.

Comment: dont abuse tags please, are you using mysql, sql server or postgresql?

Comment: I use postgresql , but if you give me and advice with mysql it will also help

Comment: Share sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you are able to join the stores table

I think you should join level_assignment (where the store_id = 1) with all data in the stores table, but subquery where the outer query excludes the store_id = 1 column from the level assignment table. You may have to create a join column in temporary tables for the stores data. Then union the level_assignment table where store_id != 1

Example:

```
WITH get_all_stores_for_store_id_1 AS (

SELECT 
a.level_assigment,
a.store_id,
b.store_id,
a.user_id
FROM level_assignment a 
LEFT JOIN stores b ON a.join_column = b.join_column
WHERE a.store_id = 1)

SELECT
level_assignment,
b.store_id AS store_id,
user_id
FROM get_all_stores_for_store_id_1 

UNION

SELECT
level_assignment,
store_id,
user_id
FROM level_assignment
WHERE store_id != 1
```

Does that make sense?

Thinking about how to join the data, we could do something like this:

Get the stores table and create a 1 column with a one in every row for the stores, so that we can then join all stores to the level_assignment table with store_id = 1:

```
WITH set_1_column_in_stores_table AS (

SELECT 
1 AS join_id,
store_id,
FROM stores),

all_store_rows_get_all_stores AS (
SELECT 
a.level_assigment,
a.store_id,
b.store_id,
a.user_id
FROM level_assignment a 
LEFT JOIN set_1_column_in_stores_table b ON a.store_id= b.join_id
-- The above will join all stores where store_id = 1 in level_assigment
WHERE a.store_id = 1)

SELECT
level_assignment,
b.store_id AS store_id,
user_id
FROM all_store_rows_get_all_stores 

UNION 

SELECT
level_assignment,
store_id,
user_id
FROM level_assignment
WHERE store_id != 1
```